# Report with subreport in subreport using JsonDataSource

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I have 3 .jrxml (main report, subreport and subreport in subreport) and get data from JSON. Paths to subreports jasper files I send like parameters (first subrreport - sub_jasper_report, second subreport - sub_jasper_report2)

JSON

```
{
  "name1": "",
  "joints": [
    {
      "name2": "1",
      "zones": [
        {
          "name3": "1"
        },
        {
          "name3": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name2": "2",
      "zones": [
        {
          "name3": "1"
        },
        {
          "name3": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Subreport in MAIN REPORT (I send array joints in the subreport and it works)

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("joints")]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report}]]></subreportExpression>
```

In the first subreport field "name" works fine. But the first subreport has subreport too (zones) and I try to send too.

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("joints.zones")]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report2}]]></subreportExpression>
```

But in the secound subreport (subreport of subreport) filed "name" doesn't work.

Looks like I have to send parameters (path to .jrxl) not only in the main report, but in the first subreport too. But I don't know how.

**MainReport**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.16.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.16.0-48579d909b7943b64690c65c71e07e0b80981928  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RK_GOST_RUS" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="758" leftMargin="56" rightMargin="28" topMargin="28" bottomMargin="28" uuid="2fecaf74-39aa-42a2-9e1d-4ef078bb2bc2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="sub_jasper_report" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Subreport]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="A9" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="10" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="758" height="10" uuid="74977f92-bc0b-4e05-8335-a22d78db9898">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("joints")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="350" y="114" width="408" height="22" uuid="6aec8b48-d3b7-443f-8ac7-3ee2fa611aee">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="1">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Liberation Serif" size="7" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A9}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="119">
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**First subreport**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.16.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.16.0-48579d909b7943b64690c65c71e07e0b80981928  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RK_GOST_RUS_SUB1" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="758" leftMargin="56" rightMargin="28" topMargin="28" bottomMargin="28" uuid="2fecaf74-39aa-42a2-9e1d-4ef078bb2bc2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="sub_jasper_report" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Subreport]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="A9" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="10" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="758" height="10" uuid="74977f92-bc0b-4e05-8335-a22d78db9898">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("zones")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="350" y="114" width="408" height="22" uuid="6aec8b48-d3b7-443f-8ac7-3ee2fa611aee">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="1">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Liberation Serif" size="7" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A9}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="119">
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Second Subreport**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.16.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.16.0-48579d909b7943b64690c65c71e07e0b80981928  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RK_GOST_RUS_SUB1" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="758" leftMargin="56" rightMargin="28" topMargin="28" bottomMargin="28" uuid="2fecaf74-39aa-42a2-9e1d-4ef078bb2bc2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="A9" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name3]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="10" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="350" y="114" width="408" height="22" uuid="6aec8b48-d3b7-443f-8ac7-3ee2fa611aee">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="1">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Liberation Serif" size="7" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{A9}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="119">
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Function in program, that all works for one subreport, but not for subreport in subreport. I get the data from json by description of field and put F (field) in "text field".

```
fun createJasper(
        jasperName: String,
        parameter: Map<String, Any>,
        json: ByteArray,
    ): JasperPrint? {
        
        val jasperReport = JRLoader.loadObject(javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(jasperName)) as JasperReport
        
        return JasperFillManager.fillReport(
            jasperReport,
            parameter,  // Path to Subreports
            if (json.isEmpty()) JREmptyDataSource() else JsonDataSource(ByteArrayInputStream(json))
        )
    }
```

Comment: Try using `zones` instead of `joints.zones` for the second subreport dataSourceExpression.

Comment: @Narcis it doesn't work, I tried

Comment: What is you desired output? Are you constrained to using subreports? Have you tried using JSONQL?

Comment: @Narcis I need dynamic table (first subreport) and some cells like one more dynamic table (second subreport)

Comment: Please post a simplified version of all your files in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Narcis Done. I deleted all useless fields etc in jasper examples.

Comment: With minor template adjustments, the Main report seems to run fine in the sense that it  displays the appropriate data from the JSON object. One possible cause for your issue might be related to the compilation of the subreports. Either compile them manually to generate the appropriate .jasper or enable the automatic build by selecting `Project` > `Build Automatically` and then trigger a rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just needed send parameters from master to subreport. And still use just parameters

```
<subreportParameter name="sub_jasper_report">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="sub_jasper_report2">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="sub_jasper_report3">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub_jasper_report3}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```